# How can I migrate this project from SVN to GIT in this simple situation?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-bash, svn2git

I have the following doubt related how to **migrate from SVN to GIT** in this specific situation.

Untill now we are using **SVN** as version control system. Now we have are switching to **GIT**.

So in this moment I only have to put on **GIT** a single projet that untill now are handled using **SVN**. Another important detail is that this project have no an history on SVN because it is a new project and at this time there is only the first commit so luckily I have not to migrate also the history from **SVN** to **GIT**.

So basically on my PC I have a Java project that currently is linked to an **SVN** repository. I have to put on **GIT** only the current version.

Can I simply go into my local project and do something like this:

```
cd existing-project-on-my-local-PC
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin https://username@my-company.com/bitbucket/scm/my-project/myproject.git
git push -u origin master
```

My project also contains the **.svn** folder containing the old svn informations. How can I exlude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it almost like that.

You should use `git add .` instead of `git add --all`, as the former adds everything in and under the current directory, while the latter only updates already tracked files.

Regarding the `.svn` directory, either simply delete it, you shouldn't need it anymore and it is probably not the best idea to have a worktree that is controlled by SVN **and** Git at the same time. Alternatively you can use Gits ignore feature to exclude the `.svn` folder. If you want to commit this exclusion together with your project, create a file `.gitignore` with content `/.svn/` (this will ignore the folder `.svn` on the same level as the `.gitignore` file and everything that is in it), or add the same to `.git/info/exclude` after doing `git init` to only ignore it in your local Git repository. Or you can also add it to the ignore file that is on user level to ignore `.svn` folders in all your local Git repositories, but I think this is not necessary. You can read more about the ignore feature at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.